# Range query for all paths in a BTreeSet that are inside a directory

Tags: rust

Given a `BTreeSet<PathBuf>` where all paths are canonicalized and refer to files, and a `&Path` (also canonicalized) that is a directory, what would be the most robust way to query for all paths in the set that are inside of the directory?

It would probably have to be something like

```
set.range(
    Included(directory_with_trailing_slash),
    Excluded(next_directory_with_trailing_slash)
)
```

but how do I get the next (in the sense of `Path`'s `Ord` implementation) directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I get the next (in the sense of Path's Ord implementation) directory?

I don't think you do, usually you take an open-ended range and then you tack on a `take_while` to only keep the elements with the prefix you need.

The alternative is likely going to be less efficient for strings: you take the next possible prefix as your upper bound, which here would be the same string with the trailing `/` replaced by a `0`.

Comment: That makes sense, you can `take_while(|path| path.starts_with(directory_with_trailing_slash))`.

Comment: FYI, I think your deleted answer on [Dependent atomic operations ordering explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76510680) is correct except for the "on real CPUs" part.  In theory there's no ordering guarantee.