# Memory ordering explanation

Tags: rust, atomic, memory-barriers

I had to study how memory ordering works recently, and I want to write result of my studies to some `readme.md` for future me(when I forget it) and other devs

## Atomic operation memory ordering explanation

### Examples

#### `do_under_spinlock_explanation`

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::Ordering;

fn do_under_spinlock_explanation() {
    let did_current_thread_acquire_lock;
    loop {
        // See [Explanation for atomic operations]
        // See [Explanation for conditional branch operations]
        did_current_thread_acquire_lock = is_locked.compare_exchange(
            0,
            1,
            // What will happen if we change Acquire to Relaxed
            // - read_and_write_memory_1-2_1-2 won't be able
            // to be reordered before
            // `if did_current_thread_acquire_lock` condition check
            // (since it will break single threaded execution),
            // which can't be run before computing `did_current_thread_acquire_lock`
            // (since using memory which
            // `if did_current_thread_acquire_lock` used(created) would
            // break single threaded logic)
            // - We won't pull actual memory, and will have stale memory
            // snapshot, so there will be race
            Acquire,
            Relaxed
        );
        if did_current_thread_acquire_lock {
            // See [Explanation for non-atomic operations]
            //
            // In which order these not atomic operations can happen?
            // - In random order, but operations on same memory can't
            // happen before previous operations on same memory,
            // since it will break single threaded logic, so
            // `read_and_write_memory_2_2` can happen before
            // `read_and_write_memory_1_1`
            // (if compiler decides that reordering will improve performance),
            // but `read_and_write_memory_2_2` can't happen before `read_and_write_memory_2_1`
            //
            // Where these not atomic operations can be reordered to top?
            // - Not before conditional check, since it would break logic
            // of single threaded execution
            //
            // Where these not atomic operations can be reordered to bottom?
            // - Not after Release, since it prevents reordering after it
            read_and_write_memory_1_1();
            read_and_write_memory_1_2();
            read_and_write_memory_2_1();
            read_and_write_memory_2_2();
            read_and_write_memory_1_and_2_1();
            read_and_write_memory_1_and_2_2();

            // What will happen if we change Release to Relaxed
            // - read_and_write_memory_1-2_1-2 won't be able
            // to be reordered after, going out of synchronized section
            // - We won't push actual memory changes, so other threads
            // will have stale memory even if they Acquire it,
            // so there will be race
            is_locked.swap(0, Release);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

#### `relaxed_counter_explanation`

````rust
fn relaxed_counter_explanation() {
    // See [Explanation for atomic operations]
    //
    // Where it can be reordered to top?
    // - Anywhere, even outside of method, until it meets operation
    // which also uses `count_1`, or until it meets other atomic
    // with Ordering::Acquire
    //
    // Where it can be reordered to bottom?
    // - Until it meets next operation which also uses `count_1`,
    // which is line
    // ```
    // if count_1_before_add == 0;
    // ```
    let count_1_before_add = count_1.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    // See [Explanation for conditional branch operations]
    //
    // Where condition check can be reordered to top?
    // - Until it meets `let count_1_before_add = ...`,
    // since that line uses(creates) same memory, and reordering before
    // would break single threaded logic
    //
    // Where condition check can be reordered to bottom?
    // - Anywhere, even outside of method,
    // until it meets other atomic with Ordering::Release,
    // since memory it uses is local and is not used locally
    if count_1_before_add == 0 {
        // See [Explanation for atomic operations]
        // See [Explanation for conditional branch operations]
        //
        // Where this operation can be moved to top?
        // - Not before `if count_1_before_add == 0` check,
        // since it would break logic of single threaded execution
        //
        // Where condition check can be reordered to bottom?
        // - Anywhere, even outside of method,
        // until it meets usage of same atomic or
        // other atomic with Ordering::Release
        //
        // Can it be placed before/after `times_when_count_1_decreased_from_1_to_0.fetch_add`?
        // - Yes!
        times_when_count_1_increased_from_0_to_1.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }

    // See [Explanation for atomic operations]
    //
    // Where it can be reordered to top?
    // - Until it meets next operation which also uses `count_1`,
    // which is line
    // ```
    // let count_1_before_add = count_1.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    // ```
    //
    // Where it can be reordered to bottom?
    // - Anywhere, even outside of method, until it meets operation
    // which also uses `count_1`, or until it meets other atomic
    // with Ordering::Release
    let count_1_before_sub = count_1.fetch_sub(1, Ordering:Relaxed);
    // See [Explanation for conditional branch operations]
    //
    // Where condition check can be reordered to top?
    // - Until it meets
    // ```
    // let count_1_before_sub = count_1.fetch_sub(1, Ordering:Relaxed);
    // ```,
    // since that line uses(creates) same memory, and reordering before
    // would break single threaded logic
    //
    // Where condition check can be reordered to bottom?
    // - Anywhere, even outside of method,
    // until it meets other atomic with Ordering::Release,
    // since memory it uses is local and is not used locally
    if count_1_before_sub == 1 {
        // See [Explanation for atomic operations]
        // See [Explanation for conditional branch operations]
        //
        // Where this operation can be moved to top?
        // - Not before `if count_1_before_sub == 1` check,
        // since it would break logic of single threaded execution
        //
        // Where condition check can be reordered to bottom?
        // - Anywhere, even outside of method,
        // until it meets usage of same atomic or
        // other atomic with Ordering::Release
        //
        // Can it be placed before/after `times_when_count_1_increased_from_0_to_1.fetch_add`?
        // - Yes!
        times_when_count_1_decreased_from_1_to_0.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }

    // Explanations for `count_2` are same as for `count_1`,
    // since it uses different memory and doesn't have not Relaxed atomics 
    let count_2_before_add = count_2.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    if count_2_before_add == 0 {
        times_when_count_2_increased_from_0_to_1.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }

    let count_2_before_sub = count_2.fetch_sub(1, Ordering:Relaxed);
    if count_2_before_sub == 1 {
        times_when_count_2_decreased_from_1_to_0.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }
}
````

### Explanation

#### Explanation for non-atomic operations

In scope of current thread, non-atomic operations
can be reordered to any place above/below,
but not before/after operations on same memory
which go before/after in code, since it would break single
threaded logic
(operation 2 can't go before 1 or after 3 on same memory,
but can go before/after operations on other memory),
and not before Acquire/AcquireRelease/SeqCst atomics in current thread,
and not after Release/AcquireRelease/SeqCst atomics in current thread

If happens after Acquire in current thread,
and Acquire in current thread happened after Release in other thread,
sees actual memory changes which happened before Release in other thread

If happens not after Acquire in current thread,
sees not actual memory, which can cause race

If happens after Acquire in current thread,
and Acquire in current thread happens not after Release in other thread,
which currently modifies memory, sees not actual memory,
without changes which will happen before Release in other thread,
which can cause race

#### Explanation for atomic operations

If Relaxed, in scope of current thread, can be reordered to
any place above/below, but not before/after operations
on same atomic(with any memory ordering) which go before/after in code,
and not before Acquire/AcquireRelease/SeqCst of other atomics in current thread,
and not after Release/AcquireRelease/SeqCst of other atomics in current thread

If Acquire,
can be reordered similar to Relaxed, but can't be reordered to bottom,
pulls memory changes which were pushed by Release in other thread

If Release,
can be reordered similar to Relaxed, but can't be reordered to top,
pushes memory changes which can be pulled by other thread

#### Explanation for conditional branch operations

Condition(boolean or switch case) calculation can be reordered
to anywhere where non-atomic(or atomic, if it is used in calculation)
operations can be reordered to

Condition check can be reordered to anywhere
where non-atomic operations can be reordered to,
but not before condition calculation
(since condition check happens after condition calculation,
which is operation on same memory,
since it creates memory with boolean or something for switch case,
which condition check will use)

Notice that operations in `if`/`switch` branches
can't go before condition check,
since it would break order of single threaded execution,
but can move to bottom even out of branch, as long they don't
meet operations on same memory or atomic Release

Comment: Right, there's no ordering for visibility from other CPUs.  In practice on real CPUs, atomic RMWs usually involve making the store globally-visible in the cache line, which that can't happen speculatively, so even the control dependency is somewhat significant, unlike with pure loads. So in practice at least the load side of the first `fetch_add` has to have finished (and the conditional branch on it retired) before the store side of the second can commit.